# How to pass variables from parent to child in helm?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am new to helm and I want to know how I can pass variables from the parent package to children.
I have a multi microservices application which consists of different helm packages as below:

```
$ tree parent/
parent/
├── charts/
│   ├── child-A-0.0.1.tgz
│   ├── child-B-0.0.1.tgz
│   └── child-C-0.0.1.tgz
├── Chart.yaml
├── templates/
│   ├── NOTES.txt
│   └── secret.yaml
└── values.yaml
```

And for example, I want to set `public-IP` in the parent `values.yaml` and when I install the parent that `public-IP` passed and set in the children as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Overriding values of a child chart](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/#overriding-values-from-a-parent-chart) is described in the Helm documentation.

In the parent chart's `values.yaml` file (or an external file you pass to `helm install -f`) you can explicitly override values for a subchart:

```yaml
childA:
  publicIP: 10.10.10.10
```

The top-level values key `global` is also always passed to child charts, but the chart needs to know to look for it.

```yaml
global:
  publicIP: 10.10.10.10
```

```yaml
env:
  - name: PUBLIC_IP
    value: {{ .Values.global.publicIP }}
```

This resolution happens fairly early in the Helm setup phase, so there's no way to pass a computed value to a subchart, or to pass the same value from the parent chart's top-level config into subcharts without restructuring things into `global`.